# Printing string with multiple placeholder formatters in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, list, printing, formatting

I'm trying to make an algorithm in Python 2.7.10 that takes user input, splits it and puts words into a list, then takes all words from that list and prints them in a specific manner.

```
usr_input = raw_input(' > ')

input = usr_input.split(' ')

print "You think that the painting is:"
print "%s" + ", %s" * len(input) + "." % ( > ? < )
```

The %s formatters work as placeholders. The problem is that the number of placeholders that will be printed as a part of the string isn't fix, it's equal to `len(input)`. Therefore I don't know how to assign values to these formatters. *(That's the " > ? < " part inside of the brackets.)*

**Note:** as this is for test purposes only, let's assume the user will only be inputting strings, not integers, etc. so that there is no need for the %r formatter.

The desired output should look somewhat like this:

```
 > nice pretty funny
You think that the painting is:
nice, pretty, funny.
```

I know this can be achieved using the `str.join(str)` method but is there a way of doing it as I explained above? Thanks.

Comment: @Anshu Kumar Thanks everyone for your contribution, Anshu Kumar managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `print ("%s" + ", %s" * (len(input) - 1) + ".") % tuple(input)`

However, IMO `', '.join(input) + '.'` is better :)

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem. Just out of curiosity, (I'm new to Python) why do you think `.join(str)` method is better to use here? (Is it better to generally use it over `str + str` for combining strings?)

Comment: More pythonic and generally faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want by doing this:

```
print ",".join(["%s"] * len(input)) % tuple(input)
```

Basically, construct your string of `"%s, "`... and pass the input as a list to the string formatters. You can do it exactly like you've written it too, just pass in your list.

```
print "%s" + ", %s" * len(input)) + "." % tuple(input)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I've tried passing it the list and I get the following:

`TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`.

Also, the first code you've attached returns:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'list'`

and the second one just `%s, &s, &s, %s.`

I'm looking to find out if there is a way of doing it without the `.join(str)` method.

Comment: Right, sorry. Edited my answer - I had a hanging parentheses error.

Comment: You realize that everyone who answered your question gave the same answer, right?

Comment: Yes, but not everyone's answer was executable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a tuple after "%". Note that you have already considered the first word in the print, so len(input) -1 words are left to be written.

```
usr_input = raw_input(' > ')

input = usr_input.split(' ')

output = "%s" + ", %s" * (len(input) - 1) + "."
print "You think that the painting is:"
print output % tuple(input)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the concept, converting input into a tuple will probably do the trick. Though I'm getting an error when trying to run your code, after inputing a few arguments. Here's what I'm talking about: ` > a
You think that the painting is:
    print "%s" + ", %s" * (len(input) - 1) + "." % tuple(input)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`.

Comment: Formatting took precedence over concatenation and thus the error.

Comment: Thank you both. I've fixed it.